# Select text across lines in cmd.exe?

Tags: windows, command-line

Is there a way to select text across lines as a single line in the Windows command prompt? For example, selecting this rectangular selection:

[image]

puts two separate lines in the clipboard, even though the lines are contiguous. Doing the same thing in xterm on Linux will put one line on the clipboard, which is what I want. Is there a way to get cmd.exe to behave like xterm?

Comment: Alternatives: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/473839/help-me-make-my-windows-cmd-exe-console-work-more-like-a-linux-terminal

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a way to select the line of text as one single line.  Before right clicking on the white highlighted area hold down the shift key, then right click the white area.  This will remove the carriage returns.

Comment: That trick works as well when you press *Enter* to copy the selection: *Shift* + *Enter* removes the CRLFs. =)

Answer (score 4):

You can export to a text file and then do as you like.  when you do your command, run it as:

```
[executable] >textfile.txt
```

This will output to the specified file anything the exe would output to the screen.

Answer (score 2):

use a terminal such as [Console2](http://sourceforge.net/projects/console/) to run your cmd.exe (or powershell.exe) from. such terminals offer (among other things) superior selecting mechanisms.

Answer (score 1):

Windows' `cmd` application is a very very basic tool. It's not intended to be used like the power-user's do-all swiss army knife that is the Linux terminal.

So basically, **no, you can't grab multiline selects as a single line.** Sorry.

Comment: Well.. Copy them, and format them in 1-2 second with Notepad++. Hard-stuff if you are a so-called "poweruser".

Comment: I wouldn't call the `cmd` a "very very basic tool"...I'd call it crippled...especially in comparison with Linux Shells.

Comment: This doesn't excuse `cmd`'s awkward selection behavior. There are no other programs that I know which select text as a rectangular area rather than a string of characters, no matter how basic.

Answer (score 0):

Installing cygwin will solve all your problems:)

Comment: and introduce new ones :)

Comment: copy style from cygwin is exactly the same AFAIK...

Answer (score 0):

As of now, there's no way to do that using `cmd.exe`, but you can use a console emulator. I am especially fond of [ConEmu](http://code.google.com/p/conemu-maximus5/), which gives you several enhancements such as:

- Better text selection
- Multiple consoles in tabs
- Resizable windows
- Fullscreen mode

Comment: there's a way to that using `cmd.exe` as of now